# What is Mike Milligan's new job at the end of Fargo Season 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, fargo-tv

This part of *Fargo*'s episode [*Palindrome*](http://fargo.wikia.com/wiki/Palindrome) (S02E10) is not clear to me.

The gangster enforcer Mike Milligan goes back to his base at Kansas City and a clerk boss shows him his new office and talks about the new job.

[image: Mike Milligan]

What happened? He has shown some talent in his gangster job so why is Mike not a gangster anymore?

Comment: He is still part of the organisation, but is no longer a hitman/field worker. Recall that during the meeting of the "big bosses" the Kansas crime syndicate is shown more like a corporation and you should get the idea.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong You might want to flesh that out into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As can be seen during the meeting of Kansas City Mafia executives in the [first episode](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/fargos-second-season-premiere-everyone-hears-stori-226733) of the season their organisation is very corporate. They have a "business plan" for the takeover of Gerhardts and present it on slides:

[image]

Based on that it's obvious that they utilise not only thugs and hitmen, but also office workers. Mike's arguable promotion is a transfer from the field into a desk work. He's still a part of the organisation, but now has different responsibilities.

The rationale behind this action is not explained. Maybe the KC Mafia leaders really appreciate his work, maybe they think he's in fact too good and see him as a potential threat or maybe he was just a pawn, controlled all the time.

Comment: Or is that a punishment for killing the Undertaker?

Comment: @Bebs That's possible too.